# "Center Of Excellence" or "Center For Excellence"

Tags: prepositions

At my place of work, we have created a new group:

> Center **Of** Excellence

which is responsible for pushing best practices throughout the organization, but my feeling is that it should be called:

> Center **For** Excellence

since their responsibility is to ***promote excellence*** and create **centers of excellence** in the other groups (eventhough it itself is a "*center* ***of*** *excellence*").

Is my thinking correct about this?

Answer (score 2):

"**Centre of Excellence**" is a widely-used term that has a range of meaning in different sectors. In healthcare, it might be a hospital department that is held up as a particularly strong example of that sort of department. One hospital might be a centre of excellence in cardiology, and another in neurology. The idea is that these hospitals both model best practice for other hospitals, and may be a tertiary referral centre - somewhere that receives patients from other hospitals in the most difficult cases.

In other sectors, it can be what you describe, a unit within an organisation that exists to promote excellence.

"**Centre for Excellence**" is, in my experience, a less-used term, but it can also mean what you're talking about. Most often it indicates an organisation or department that is not working only within its own organisation, but to promote excellence in other organisations as well. A "Centre for Excellence **in Teaching**" exists to identify and promote the best techniques and practices in teaching.